# what functions to use to switch between widgets in gtk+

Tags: gtk

hi im building a gui for my embedded project ,im using a custom 4bit keypad . im trying to switch between widgets using a switch(similar to TAB) but im not able to find the internal functions used to implement it . can anybody suggest where to find those implementations ?

Comment: Can you try to rephrase the question? It's not clear what you want. [GtkNotebook](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkNotebook.html) is a tabbed container if that's what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find widget switching is hard coded to the tab key. You would need to make a switch generate the same code as a tab key.